# How to get text from programmatically added UITextView [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Iam adding textFields with this code to add 3 UITextFields to ViewController:

```
for var index = 0; index < 3; ++index {
    var textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40))
    var pom:CGFloat = 130 + CGFloat(index*50)
    textField.center = CGPointMake(185, pom)
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(textField)
}
```

and now i need to get text from all textFields. Can someone tell me, how can i make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store them in an array, set the `tag` property on each one with the value of the counter in your loop, then retrieve them by that tag later on:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var textFields = [UITextField]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for var index = 0; index < 3; ++index {
            var textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40))
            var pom:CGFloat = 130 + CGFloat(index*50)
            textField.center = CGPointMake(185, pom)
            textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
            textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
            textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            textField.tag = index
            self.textFields.append( textField )
            self.view.addSubview(textField)
        }

        for var index = 0; index < 3; ++index {
            if let textField = self.textFieldForTag( index ) {
                print( textField.text )
            }
        }
    }

    func textFieldForTag( tag: Int ) -> UITextField? {
        return self.textFields.filter({ $0.tag == tag }).first
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use tags then why not skip the array and use viewWithTag to fetch the fields? And if you're going to save them, then why not just save the text fields in individual instance variables  and use those iVars to fetch the text from each one? Or if you want to use an array, then create an enum with the indexes of each field and just do a lookup by index using the raw value of each enum?

Comment: Ahhh, cool!  I didn't know about `viewWithTag(_:)`  Only limitation I guess is that it only searches among subviews of the view upon which its called.  iVars or enum values is probably appropriate for this example with only 3 text fields.  An array like mine would be more for something larger or more dynamic.